# Many to many JPQL @Query with List as argument in Spring

Tags: spring, list, jpa, many-to-many, jpql

I've got a simple Product-Category many-to-many relationship, where Product has a List< Category> "categories" attribute, and Category has a List< Product> "products" attribute. JPA ORM mapping is pretty ok and working.

In the ProductRepository, I'd like to include a method that takes a partial name and a list of Category as parameter, and returns all products that contain the given name and **any of the categories in the parameter list**. My question is: is it possible to specify my query inside a @Query? How?

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT obj FROM Product obj WHERE obj.name LIKE %?1 AND obj.categories ?????")
    List<Product> findByNameCategories(String name, List<Category> categorias);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can craft your query to do what you want without having to use the `@Query` annotation

```
List<Product> findByNameStartingWithAndCategoriesIn(String name, Set<Category> categorias);
```

For distinct results:

```
Set<Product> findDistinctByNameStartingWithAndCategoriesIn(String name, Set<Category> categorias);
```

Spring will automatically create the proper query for you. You can also you `EndingWith` to wrap the parameter ending with % or `Containing` to have the parameter be wrapped on both sides with %

I changed your `List<Category> categorias` to a Set because list can have duplicate Category objects in the list while a Set will not so when it crafts the query behind the scenes you'll have unique ids in the In clause.

[Spring Documentation on crafting queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Comment: Awesome use of standard names, thank you. Just one question: the method was returning repeated products. In order to get distinct products, I replaced the returning type to Set< Product> but here is my question: apparently all repeated values come from database and then they are post-filtered by the Set datastructure. Is there a better way to get distinct values? In other words: to get distinct values direct from database?